# Simplify SUM, COUNT with criteria

Tags: ms-access

I have a table named `FIK2015`. How to simplify this SQL? It takes so long to process.

```
SELECT t1.AGILIR, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM FIK2015 t2
    WHERE t2.AGILIR = t1.AGILIR AND t2.GRED01  = 'A'
) +
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM FIK2015 t3
    WHERE t3.AGILIR = t1.AGILIR AND t3.GRED02 = 'A'
) +
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM FIK2015 t4
    WHERE t4.AGILIR = t1.AGILIR AND t4.GRED03 = 'A'
) & "A" & " " & 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM FIK2015 t9
    WHERE t9.AGILIR = t1.AGILIR AND t9.GRED01 = 'B'
) +
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM FIK2015 t10
    WHERE t10.AGILIR = t1.AGILIR AND t10.GRED02 = 'B'
) +
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM FIK2015 t11
    WHERE t11.AGILIR = t1.AGILIR AND t11.GRED03 = 'B'
) & "B" & " " &  
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM FIK2015 t16
    WHERE t16.AGILIR = t1.AGILIR AND t16.GRED01 = 'C'
) +
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM FIK2015 t17
    WHERE t17.AGILIR = t1.AGILIR AND t17.GRED02 = 'C'
) +
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM FIK2015 t18
    WHERE t18.AGILIR = t1.AGILIR AND t18.GRED03 = 'C'
) & "C" & " " & 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM FIK2015 t23
    WHERE t23.AGILIR = t1.AGILIR AND t23.GRED01 = 'D'
) +
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM FIK2015 t24
    WHERE t24.AGILIR = t1.AGILIR AND t24.GRED02 = 'D'
) +
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM FIK2015 t25
    WHERE t25.AGILIR = t1.AGILIR AND t25.GRED03 = 'D'
) AS RESULT
FROM FIK2015 AS t1
GROUP BY t1.AGILIR;
```

This is my table:

| AGILIR | GRED01 | GRED02 | GRED03 | expected result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| L0011001 | A | B | A | 2A |
| L0011002 | A | B | B | 1A |
| L0011003 | A | A | C | 2A |
| L0011004 | A | A | C | 2A |

Comment: I can't but help wondering if your tables are normalized properly?  Usually fields such as GRED01, GRED02, GRED03 would usually indicate that they are not.  Without knowing your table structure it's hard to know.  Have you tried doing a seperate count query, grouping by your three GRED columns (Where all three are equal), then doing an inner join to that table?  Can you provide sample data for this query?

Comment: Tq, I give sample table above.